# Open a tab and get the pagesource

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new tab, and log the page_source in the console.

```
function getRespons(autor, message) {
  var urlstring = "?a=" + autor + "&m=" + message;
  var encodedurl = encodeURI(urlstring);
  var win = window.open('http://127.0.0.1/gate.php' + encodedurl, '_blank');
  if (win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
    console.log(window.document.body.innerHTML);
    win.close();
  } else {
    //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
  }
}
```

There is some HTML being printed in the console, however this is the HTML of the first tab and not the recent opened one.

Comment: have you tried `win.document.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't provide me anything. Just an empty string. I've checked the tab by not closing it and there must be some HTML to log in the console.

Comment: maybe the window hasn't loaded yet? Try using onload

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout method.

```
          if (win) {
            //Browser has allowed it to be opened
            win.focus();
            setTimeout(function(){ 
               console.log(win.document.body.innerHTML);
                win.close();
            }, 5000);
         }
```